# Doubt in $S$-polynomial and lemma $5$ of chapter 2 of Cox, Little and O'Shea

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

This the lemma from the Cox, Little and O'Shea book which asks me to prove the following

Suppose we have a sum $\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$, where $c_i \in k$ and multideg($f_i)=\delta \in Z^{n}\mid n \geq 0$ for all i. If multideg ($\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}) < \delta, $ then $\sum_{i=1}^{s} {c_i f_i}$ is a linear combination, with coefficients in $K$, of the $S$-polynomials $S(f_j,\,f_k) \; \text{for} \;1 \leq j,k \leq s$. Furthermore each $S(f_i,\:f_k)$ has multidegree $< \delta$.

This lemma really doesn't make sense to me. I can't get any intuition as to why are we proving this. What is the significance of the $S$-polynomials ? I need someone to explain this with an example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what context does this appear in the book? How is the lemma used?

Comment: This is proved just before proving the bucherberg's criterion

Comment: That answers one of your questions: The significance of $S$-polynomials is their appearance in Buchberger's criterion for determining wether a generating set of an ideal is a Gröbner basis (and also in the Buchberger algorithm).

Comment: Yes but why are we proving this lemma .What does it want to say?

Comment: The lemma says that all cancelling in principle is accounted for by $S$-polynomials.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand it

Comment: Try to read this book further. There it is explained with examples.